# Hibernate criteria eqOrIsNull return wrong value

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have class which mapped to db.
This is my criteria API function with hibernate:

```
public List<Department> getDepartmentBy(Account account)
{
    return createCriteria(Department.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("account ", account))
            .add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("archive", false))
            .list();
}
```

Without eqOrIsNull i have 8 records with archieve = null in DB.

My class:

```
private Account _account;
private boolean _archive = false;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_l", nullable = false)
public Account getAccount ()
{
    return _account;
}

public void setAccount(Account account)
{
    _account = account;
}

@Column(name = "archive_p")
public boolean isArchive()
{
    return _archive;
}

public void setArchive(boolean archive)
{
    _archive = archive;
}
```

Is it bug? Or did i use wrong criteria API?

**UPD**: Exact explanaition
I have 8 records in database with archive_p equals null. When i want select records with 'false' or null at 'archive' field, i use `add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("archive", false))`. I need records with NULL or with 'false'. But when i add `.add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("archive", false))` i get 0 records in result.

Comment: can you describe the exact issue that you are facing?

Comment: add update, but get right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use wrong criteria API, the source of `eqOrIsNull()`

```
public static Criterion eqOrIsNull(String propertyName, Object value) {
    return value == null
            ? isNull( propertyName )
            : eq( propertyName, value );
}
```

It adds null check only if `value == null`. You pass `value == false`.

Comment: i think its perfect method for me. return value or if value equals null return null. Thanks!

Comment: @flybox You are welcome. It is a bad restriction method because of It is used improperly often.